# How to sort array by subarray key and value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hello everybody :) this is my first question, so I hope for answer :)
I've got an array of arrays like this :

```
Array(
    [] => Array ([category] => 3 )
    [] => Array ([price] => 5 )
    [] => Array ([rating] => 1 )
    [] => Array ([price] => 3 )
    [] => Array ([category] => 1 )
    [] => Array ([category] => 2 )
    )
)
```

Question : How could I sort it for ex. alphanumerically by subarray key and subarray value, so that it is converted like the one following?

```
Array(
    [] => Array ([category] => 1 )
    [] => Array ([category] => 2 )
    [] => Array ([category] => 3 )
    [] => Array ([price] => 3 )
    [] => Array ([price] => 5 )
    [] => Array ([rating] => 1 )
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php):

```
$x = Array(
    Array ("category" => 3 ),
    Array ("price" => 5 ),
    Array ("rating" => 1 ),
    Array ("price" => 3 ),
    Array ("category" => 1 ),
    Array ("category" => 2 ),

);

array_multisort(
    array_map('key', $x), 
    array_map('current', $x), 
    $x);

print_r($x);
```